# How to cast an object to UnderlyingSystemType class dynamically?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, reflection

I am trying to retrieve values of returned object through `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` method of reflection, which contains an object one of the following class:

```
   Class NDataSeriesDouble: NDataSeries<double>
    {}

    Class NDataSeriesString: NDataSeries<string>
    {}
```

//code to get list value at run time

```
GetNthValueOfSereis(int n)
{
   NHitTestResult hitTestResult = chartControl.HitTest(mouseXPoint, mouseYPoint)
    // Get the sereis type object from Base class of this.
    Type seriesType = hitTestResult.Series.GetType();
    object seriesValues=  seriesType.GetProperty("Values")
                .GetValue(hitTestResult.Series, null) 

**///How i get value from this object seriesValues**

}
```

*seriesValues object contains NDataSeriesDouble or NDataSeriesString class object.*

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I imagine whoever down voted did so because it's a poorly written/formatted question.

Comment: this library is not created by me.. so i am not sure how much type of series available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to add an interface to the `NDataSeries<T>` which is not generic.

If it is not your class, and if you don't find any non-generic interfaces on this type, you need to use reflection.

Comment: How i get value from this object seriesValues. it's Count property show 6 elements. but i am not able to cast to some another type so that i can get the values of this collection.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you want from your question but for runtime type conversion you can use the [Convert](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDsQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.71%29.aspx&ei=QElrT6ulGoWf0QXl3IzSBg&usg=AFQjCNHpnuJy9-JdoTGJLu1616qsuzFAng&sig2=cJ2RNd0lWxtMaMYSG3m9kA) class.

```
object result = Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(MyTypeToConvertTo));
```

Reading your other comments it sounds like actually you want to get the items inside. You might just be able to foreach over it, if not you could try casting seriesValues as an IEnumerable and then foreach over it, alternatively try calling GetEnumerator on it and enumerate the values that way.

Comment: yes.. somewhat like this.  Is it possible to convert as: `Convert.ChangeType( seriesValues, seriesValues.GetType());`  ?

Comment: It sounds like actually what you want is casting, but you need to know you're type at design time... Converting seriesValues to it's same type won't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just cast it to its class?

```
var seriesValues = (Nevron.Chart.NDataSeriesDouble) seriesType
    .GetProperty("Values").GetValue(hitTestResult.Series, null);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion..  but i have mentioned unknown type is that it may possible next time other type of Series Class take place underlying the seriesValues object. i want it to cast it with identification of underlying series class.

Comment: underlying class changes as per the chart type.

Comment: Well, `NDataSeriesDouble` implements the `ICollection` interface, so I don't know what's the problem with casting. What error message do you get?